# HTML, CSS: Hovering creates doubled images but only on Smartphone Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am building a webpage for my startup, but I am having trouble using the mouse over / hover event. It regards this page: [www.innomotion-media.com](http://www.innomotion-media.com)

As you can see, hovering with your mouse over one of the three images will change the image to a colored one. This is working fine, however: when opening said link on a smartphone (at least on my Samsung S8 with Google Chrome) the images are shown twice. The black and white one and the colored one. So there are 6 images instead of only the wanted two.

I tried opening the page on my smartphone with Firefox and this showed correctly. 
Also I tried with Internet Explorer on my computer and it also worked.

This is the HTML that I used:

```
    <div class="container">

        <div align="center">
        <a href="./page_construction.html">
            <div class="card">          
                <img src="./img/index_left_bw.png" alt="Card Back">             
                <img src="./img/index_left.png" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">           
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
        <a href="./page_appDev.html">
            <div class="card">          
                <img src="./img/index_center_bw.png" alt="Card Back">               
                <img src="./img/index_center.png" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">         
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
        <a href="./page_recording.html">
            <div class="card">          
                <img src="./img/index_right_bw.png" alt="Card Back">                
                <img src="./img/index_right.png" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">          
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And this is the corresponding CSS:;

```
/*font face*/

  @font-face {
      font-family: "Baiti";
      src: url("./fonts/baiti.ttf");
    }
    body { font-family: "Baiti", serif }

.container{
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
}

.card {

    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

}

.card .img-top {

    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    left: 0;

    z-index: 99;

}

.card:hover .img-top {

    display: inline;

}
```

Is there maybe a better way of doing this, so that it will look the same on all browsers, smartphone or not?

I hope you can help me, this is my first time asking anything :)

Thank you!

Comment: You are showing `.img-top`, but you are not hiding the other image. You need to `display: none` on bw image or you should use `position: absolute` also on that

Comment: Instead of using two images, I would display the colour one with a greyscale filter on it that you remove on hover.  Much cleaner imo!

Comment: Hello. using display:none on img-top stops the effect from happening. the image is simply not swapped. using position:absolute didnt have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: @Martin this sounds like a good idea. Would you mind posting how this is done? that would be epic! :)

Comment: @user11480561 I've put an example in an answer below to show you how this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using overlaid images, you could use a grayscale filter in CSS on a colour image which is removed on hover.

Remove the second image from the HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <a href="./page_construction.html">
        <div class="card">          
            <img src="./img/index_left.png" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">           
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Remove the exsting CSS for `.img-top` and replace with this:

```
.card .img-top {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.card .img-top:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

The colour image will be shown but with a grayscale filter on it, so that the image is black and white.  When you hover over it, the filter is removed and the image is shown in normal colour.

This removes the need to have two images with one positioned absolutely.

Comment: thank you. however, I am tring to achieve the opposite: hovering over the image will turn a black and white version into a colored one. is this still posible?

Comment: Have you tried the code? That's exactly what it does! The code applies a black and white filter by _default_ and removes it when you _hover_ to restore the image to colour

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I tried it and it does work as it should. However, on google chrome, the images are completeley messed up still. It is a good solution though, because it decreases needed server space. But not quite perfect. I am voting you up but my low rep wont affect the publicy displayed score. :( it is recorded however :)

Comment: @user11480561 Thank you for the feedback.  How are the images messed up on Chrome? You should only have 3 images now as you should have removed all of the B&W ones

Comment: EDIT: on google chrome the images start off as colored and not black and white as on all the other browsers.

Comment: @user11480561 That's probably because it's using cached CSS.  Trying clearing the cache on the mobile browser and it should work.  I've just tested it myself and it's working for me